# How Can I show only selected div elements based on a certain condition in angularjs using ng-hide

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The aim here is to either show or hide the below div element based on my preference

```
<div ng-repeat="data_training in data.training track by $index">
                                        <h4 ng-hide="data_training.list == [] && data_training.note == '' ">WHAT TYPE OF TRAINING IS REQUIRED TO START THIS VENTURE</h4> 
                                        {{data_training.note}}
                                            <ul ng-repeat="data_training_lists in data_training.list track by $index ">
                                                <li>
                                                    {{data_training_lists}}
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
```

This is just a snippet of my index.html and below is a snippet of my json data

```
 "training": [
      {
        "note": "",
        "list": [
          "Agricultural extension officers ",
          "Agricultural shops ",
          "Non Government Organisations, Community Based Organisations ",
          "Other farmers "
        ]
      }
    ],
```

wanted to display the h4 element if and if only either training.note or training.list have value on them. THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: data_training.list == [] will return false even if data_training.list is empty because I think they are representing the same object (same memory address).

Answer (score 1):

Just check if length > 0 :

```
<h4 ng-hide="data_training.list.length && data_training.note.length">WHAT TYPE OF TRAINING IS REQUIRED TO START THIS VENTURE</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<h4 ng-if="data_training.list.length && data_training.note.length">WHAT TYPE OF TRAINING IS REQUIRED TO START THIS VENTURE</h4>
```

Or with `ng-show`

```
<h4 ng-show="data_training.list.length && data_training.note.length">WHAT TYPE OF TRAINING IS REQUIRED TO START THIS VENTURE</h4>
```

Or with `ng-hide`

```
<h4 ng-hide="data_training.list.length && data_training.note.length">WHAT TYPE OF TRAINING IS REQUIRED TO START THIS VENTURE</h4>
```

I prefer using `ng-if` over `ng-show`

> The ng-if directive removes the content from the page and
>   ng-show/ng-hide uses the CSS display property to hide content.

Comment: 'data_training.list.length > 0' could just be 'data_training.list.length' since any value above 0 will be truthy, and 0 would be falsey.

Comment: thanks @daan.desmedt it worked, but instead of &&, should use || because i still wanted to show the h4 element if either the note or the list exists.

Comment: Exactly, if you want to show when on of the 2 conditions matches, you should use `||` (or)